# Unable to get json from external url using jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Here is my code

```
       $.ajax({
    type:"GET", 
    url: "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/100/", 
    success: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        },
   dataType: "json"
});
```

But when i run it i'm getting error.The `jqXHR.status is 0` , textStatus is `Error` and errorThrown is `No Transport`

Comment: [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Yahoos YQL as JSONP proxy.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", {
    q: "select * from json where url=\"http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/100/\"",
    format: "json"
},

function (data) {
    console.log(data.query.results.json.transfers_out);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zZy77/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because you're trying to make cross-domain request.

you might want to check out JSONP as a solution instead.

Check out this http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: Updated the answer with link

Comment: but to use jsonp i need to modify the json output of the external site too rite?but i dont have control over the external site

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap JSON response in a function if you don't have access then consider using proxy.

Comment: is it possible to do using javascript only?

Comment: CORS is another option as mentioned above. jQuery.support.cors = true;